# I can't use <> (Angle Brackets) in my US keyboard in LatinAmerican Spanish input language

Tags: keyboard

My problem is that I can't write "<" or ">" in my keyboard. I have a laptop (Acer Aspire E 15 E5-576-392H) from the USA that I use with Spanish Latin American input source.

I've tried to do custom keyboard shortcuts using `<` as command and, for example, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> and a lot of other combinations without success.

I don't have the usual "<>" key.

The following is a picture of my keyboard.

[image: My Acer Aspire E 15 Keyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for <

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for >

In general you can study the symbols of the keyboard layout you are using via *Show Keyboard Layout*.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used the show keyboard layout but it shows a keyboard with the >< key that i haven't.

Comment: @Julián: It does, but it also shows those symbols on the Z and X keys, doesn't it?